# Access another table in foreach by ID

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have two tables - **Goods** and **Tax**.
They look something like this.

```
Goods
----------
idGoods    INT primary key 
title      VARCHAR 
tax_idTax  INT foreigh key 
etc..

Tax
----------
idTax     INT primary key 
title     VARCHAR 
value     INT
```

Now I have function that via foreach lists everything from goods.
But instead of `tax_idTax` I need it to be shown as it's value.

Thank you for help.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you wanting this to be performed in the php code or SQL? You might want to look at one of the various guides available on [how to ask a question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask)

Comment: This is called a `join` and is a very basic part of the SQL language.  I think you need to learn some SQL.  There are plenty of books and on-line resources that explain the subject.

Comment: I created static function getGoods() that gets everything from table goods. Then I stored it into variable $goods which I use for foreach. And yes in PHP code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why don't you

```
SELECT g.title, ..., t.value as 'tax value' FROM Goods AS g INNER JOIN Tax AS t on (g.tax_idTax = t.idTax)
```

and then traverse the rows fetched with your foreach loop ?

Answer (score 0):

u can try this ,it will work

```
    SELECT
     g.title,(etc).,
    t.value AS
 'tax value' 
    FROM 
    Goods
     AS 
    g 
    INNER JOIN 
    Tax
     AS 
    t ON
     (g.tax_idTax = t.idTax)
```